# CTE "Expected: Expression" from If (Not Double.TryParse(String, Double))

Tags: vba, ms-access

```
Function LatToDecimal(latIn As String) As String
    Dim SplitA() As String
    SplitA() = Split(latIn, "°") 'A(0) is DEG.
    Dim SplitB() As String
    SplitB() = Split(SplitA(1), "'") 'B(0) is MIN.
    Dim SplitC() As String
    SplitC() = Split(SplitB(1), """") 'C(0) is SEC. C(1) is N/S.

    Dim deg As Double
    Dim min As Double 'Not yet used.
    Dim sec As Double 'Not yet used.

    If (Not Double.TryParse(SplitA(0), deg)) Then
        deg = 0
    End If

End Function
```

When building the above function, I get a compile error (Expected: Expression) on the `If` statement. `latIn` will always pass as a valid DMS latitude value, and I have confirmed (though `MsgBox(SplitA(0))` which has since been removed) that `SplitA(0)` does in fact exist.

It seems as though `Double.TryParse()` is not successfully returning a Boolean value, unless I misunderstand. What could be causing this to occur?

Comment: Are you programming in vba or vb.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If memory serves me correct `Double.TryParse()` is for VB.net.  I think what you are looking for is Cdbl to convert it over into a double.  You can find more information about that here: http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/datatype/cdbl.php

It is a fantastic resource for almost all built in functions you will ever need.

Comment: This seems to have done it-- I had seen something about `CDbl` floating around, but couldn't figure out the difference between the two. Thank you for the prompt response!